# Rails - filtering multiple tables with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing an online word learning project and i want to making a search feature where you can filter word by lessons, words and learning status (learned/unlearned). Filter by lessons and words are done. I'm stuck at the last filter condition. I'm using scope and the params for learn status just can't seems to get to the scope, the "words" table and "user_words" table won't join (i tried with these two tables first).

**Here are my tables:**

```
create_table "users" do |t|
  t.string "username"
end

create_table "words" do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "lesson_id"
end

create_table "user_words" do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "word_id"
  t.boolean "status"
end
```

**My models:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_words
end

class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_words

  scope :order_name_asc, -> {order name: :asc}

  scope :search_prefix, -> prefix {where "name like ?", "#{prefix}%"}

  scope :search_lesson, -> lesson_id {
    where("lesson_id = ?", lesson_id) if lesson_id.present?}

  # Is the problem here?
  scope :search_learned, -> (learned) do
    joins(:user_words).where("user_words.status = ?", 
    learned[:user_word_status].to_i) if learned[:user_word_status]
  end
end

class UserWord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :word
end
```

**My controller**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_lessons, only: :home
  before_action :load_user_words, only: :home

  def home
    @words = Word.search_learned(learned: params[:learned]) #or the problem's here
      .search_lesson(params[:lesson_id])
      .search_prefix(params[:prefix]).order_name_asc
      .paginate page: params[:page]
  end
end
```

**And the view:**

```
# Lesson filter option:
<%= select_tag :lesson_id,
  grouped_options_for_select(@categories.map {|category| 
    [category.name,category.lessons.map {|lesson| [lesson.name, 
      lesson.id]}]}),
  include_blank: t(".all_lessons"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

# Learning status filter option (is the problem here?):
<%= select_tag :learned, 
  options_for_select(@user_words.map(&:status)),
  include_blank: t(".learned"), class: "btn btn-secondary" %>

# Text input fied, submit button and the word list:
<%= text_field_tag :prefix, params[:prefix],
  placeholder: t(".search"), class: "form-control" %>
<%= submit_tag t(".search"), name: nil, class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% @words.each do |word| %>
  <%= link_to word.name, "#" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _'the "words" table and "user_words" table won't join'_?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh i tried to join the two tables so i can select words from the joined table where the value in status column equal to the parameter.
But when i click the submit button and check the terminal, it just show:
    "Word Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `words`.* FROM `words` WHERE (name like '%') ORDER BY `words`.`name` ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0"